# Как избавиться от ошибки при установке пакета?

Tags: python

Python 3.3, установка pyDNS выдает ошибку, в чем может быть причина?

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pydns
Downloading/unpacking pydns
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pydns
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "d:\temp\pip-build\pydns\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        import DNS
      File "d:\temp\pip-build\pydns\DNS\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
        import Type,Opcode,Status,Class
    ImportError: No module named 'Type'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>    
  File "d:\temp\pip-build\pydns\setup.py", line 12, in <module>    
    import DNS    
  File "d:\temp\pip-build\pydns\DNS\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>    
    import Type,Opcode,Status,Class    
ImportError: No module named 'Type'
```

Comment: Загляните сюда(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named). Надеюсь поможет

Comment: Нет, это не то. Я так понял, что не хватает каких-то модулей, зависимостей. Но не могу найти, где же находится модуль Type. Может он в составе какого-то другого модуля? Но к сожалению не знаю его названия.

Comment: Type,Opcode,Status,Class - эти все модули содержатся в pyDNS. Может быть из-за того, что запустили с каталога system32? может просто pip пытается сделать в нем временный каталог и это не получается. Поэтому дальше файл и не находит - распаковать не удалось. Либо распаковал, но потом не может файл найти.

Comment: Смена каталога ничего не изменила. Я даже Temp назад на С: перенес, но бестолку. А так cmd конечно из-под админа, причину понять не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Банально библиотека не совместима с Python 3.3.

По [ссылке](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydns/files/py3dns/) качайте версию py3dns-3.0.2.tar.gz

Распакуйте и пишите:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Да, я тоже уже это понял и была попытка установить, но все равно приводит к ошибке, но уже другой. 
Поискав ответ на эту ошибку, нашел такое: inet_ntop есть только в Unix. (http://www.python-forum.de/viewtopic.php?t=29461&p=223349)  Как поступить дальше, пока не знаю.